# Can I make a lattice of the classes of subgroups related by outer automorphism for D8xC2?

Tags: group-theory, coloring, lattice-orders, automorphism-group, dihedral-groups

While trying to come up with a coloring scheme to organize all the complex interactions of the D8×C2 lattice, I realized I can make a much simpler lattice like structure of the kind of subgroups related by outer automorphisms. I don't know if this is a lattice or not. However, it has been really useful for me while trying to understand the actual subgroup lattice. The blue subgroups are all normal cores. The green subgroups are all 2-subnormal subgroups. The yellow subgroups are related to conjugate closure. The grey subgroups are all central. Does anyone know terms for this kind of thing, or could point me in the direction of resources related to this? Assume each point on the larger lattice is a unique subgroup of D8xC2

[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't understand all that group theoretic reasoning. What I can tell you is that the lower diagram is definitely a lattice (the direct product of three chains with two, two and three elements). The first diagram, well, there are repeated elements; I can only suppose that that can be very useful in some group theory reasoning, but it's not a lattice. Now, if you identify the nodes with the same name, you get the lower lattice back, right? But I guess you already know that.

Comment: The one above is definitely a lattice. Here is a much messier version of it https://www.math.colostate.edu/~jwilson/math/16/D8xC2.html

Comment: OK, your diagram may look much better, but you have repeated names in the nodes (no such thing in the linked diagram). As such, it's not even a partially ordered set. For the second one, it corresponds to the [sixth example here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_lattice#Examples), if you take $n$ to be any natural of the form $p_1p_2p_3^2$, where $p_1, p_2, p_3$ are different prime numbers. It's also easy to verify directly that it is a lattice.